# Twitter bootstrap 3 modal NOT working Rails 4 production (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, bootstrap-modal

I am running into an issue when I am deploying my app to heroku servers. On development (localhost:3000) everything works fine, when I launch the app some of my javascript is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your assets are not precompiled. Check browser's console for missing files.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue.

Turns out it had to do with bootstap reading the gems that were local on my machine. When I went to go push to heroku it was causing issues since I didnt precompile my assets and having all the gems was causing confusion so I removed them and added the bootstrap CDN and added it to the end of my body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has very thorough [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) on getting the Rails Asset Pipeline working on there. Make sure you also use your browser development tools to help you identify 404 errors with assets or any other issues that can help you diagnose the problem.